# How to reinstall npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, uninstallation

Last time I typed the following commands in cmd:

```
npm config set prefix "D:\nodejs\node_global"
npm config set cache "D:\nodejs\node_cache"
```

However, then I found that I've entered the wrong path. Actually my `node_global` and `node_cache` are in `F` disk, while I even don't have `D`
disk in my computer. Now, no matter what `npm` command I enter, such as

```
npm -v
```

Or

```
npm install <package_name> -g
```

, there will be the following error:

```
UNKNOWN: unknown error, mkdir 'D:\nodejs\node_global' at Error <native>
```

I have tried to reinstall the `nodejs`, but the error still exists. Therefore, I want to know that if there is any method that can remove `npm` and then install it again? Or if there is any other solution that can fix my problem?

Comment: Did you try `npm config rm prefix` and `npm config rm cache`?

Comment: Or probably `npm config delete prefix` since it seems that you are on windows

Comment: Yes, I've tried this comand, and then there will be the error: mkdir 'D:\nodejs\node_global'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file named `.npmrc` in your home directory(`C:\Users\yourname`) and simply remove this line `prefix=D:\nodejs\node_global`